# How to persist the cron job in NEST JS after server restart?

Tags: mysql, cron, nestjs

I'm facing a problem in running the Nest JS cron job in sync with Mysql database. The problem right now is once the server gets restarted all the cron jobs are lost. What is the best way to get the existing cron jobs which was set before ?

Comment: Please elaborate on how your cron jobs are specified. Code examples would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I found it's creating a crons table in the db and use the OnModuleInit provided by NestJS and retrieve all the crons from DB and run them inside the OnModuleInit method.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend running cronjobs in your primary server. The cronjobs you run in NestJs are run in the same node process. So if you restart the server, they are all lost.

It's better to run cronjobs in another node process. (you start another nestJs app that does only the cronjobs).

The reason is that you want to monitor cronjobs and decouple them from the main application

Clouds like [render.com](https://render.com/) have a cronjob section, for instance.